# Where can I find some prostitutes in Grand Theft Auto?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

In order to complete 100% of the game, you must get *serviced* by a prostitute. The problem is, I can't seem to find any. The one time I did a message came up on the screen stating something to the effect, "You cannot pickup a prostitute in this vehicle".

- What requirements must be met to pick up a prostitute?
- If I recall, I only found this one at night time, can I find them during the day too?
- How much does one cost?

Comment: What are you trying to pick them up in, a motorcycle..?

Comment: @DangerZone It was a truck, I don't remember which kind but I had stolen it from someone else prior to.

Comment: Just take a normal car from your collection. Or steal one... Something normal though.

Comment: @DangerZone I take that back... I remember now I was driving around in my armored Kuruma.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Vehicle Requirements:** Since Grand Theft Auto IV, Prostitutes have had specific requirements for cars that they can do their "magic" in. They cannot be picked up in the following vehicles:

- Emergency Vehicles
- Bikes (for obvious reasons)
- Buses

Some vehicles are restricted due to size, as it can be heard that "I bet you're flexible, but not in here," or "I think this car is a little too small for that..."

Also, some prostitutes are called **Luxury** or **Popular** prostitutes, and you need a flashy, expensive car to pick them up.

Just basically use a generic civilian car.

**Time Requirements:** Prostitutes are **only** findable at night, as it seems like it is only then when they show their true colors.

**Locations:**
[image: Hooker Locations]

**Cost:** Prostitutes are very cheap, with 3 options for services, costing you $50, $70, or $100. All 3 have different lengths and descriptions.

Note: You can kill them afterwards to get your money back.

**Make sure you take them to a secluded place, be generous, make sure you use protection, and good luck with the ladies!**

[Source](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Prostitutes)